# Conditional formatting for cells based on multiple other cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Image attached for spreadsheet.
I am trying to conditionally format a range based on multiple criteria, and cannot figure out the best way to do it. Basically, I want to highlight a range (ex: V4:V18) where the Affected Dates in the Change Log match the dates on the schedule AND the corresponding employee initials. The point of this is if there is something in the change log for a specific date and employee, that day gets highlighted in the schedule for that employee.

Example (see image): I want to highlight in V4:V18 where F23:F25 matches B4:B18 AND H23:H25 matches V3. So, this would highlight V5 and V6.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcmA2.jpg)

Comment: I think it would be fairly straightforward to highlight in a single colour, but if you needed to (say) show matches for different employees in different colours, you would need as many rules as employees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that values in F23:F25 are formatted as dates in 2022, you could use this custom formula in CF:

```
=COUNTIFS($F$23:$F$25,$B4,$H$23:$H$25,C$3)
```

[image]